# Cannot get asset from custom user field, with no-admin account

Tags: craft3, custom-field

I would like to get a file of custom user field, which is "asset", and provide a link to the file for the user.

However, the asset file cannot be gotten.
The length of the asset field is zero.
In addition, this issue happens only the `currentUser` is not admin.
With admin account, the asset is gotten without any trouble.

Of course, the user has a permission to view the asset volume.

The asset volume has public URLs.
On the other hand, the asset folder is out of web folder, but I do not realy think it is the cause because the asset file can be gotten with admin account.

And, my Craft is ver 3.1.33.

Comment: [Edit]: Try clearing the entire craft3 cms cache prior to the below advised testing to be sure that it's no simple caching issue of some sort.
[Original]:
Are there any differences between the assets link if accessed by admin compared to non-admin? And can you also try out opening said links while not logged in at all?
This might be helpful towards figuring out wherein the issue lies. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 1) I cleared Craft cache, but the result is same. 2) With admin account, the link to the document is provided correctly. But with non-admin account, the link is not displayed because the asset field is empty. 3) Even with the non-admin account, it is possible to open the file with putting its URL directly. However, without login, the file is protected and the access is denied.

Comment: Can you turn on `devmode` and clear all your logs under `storage/runtime/logs/*` and then try and access/get the image to appear for a `non-admin user` and after that upload the logs in a zip to some file-host? It'll be easier to see if there's some error going on. (If you don't want to upload logs, simply replying with a list of the log files generated would already help out quite a bit)

Comment: Can you share the code you have currently?